# Cannot access apicontroller method - returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have 2 c# asp.net projects. 1 is an api. 1 is consuming this api.

My api:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public dynamic ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        return myValidationMethod(token);
    }
}
```

Consuming my api from another project:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var url = "http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken";
        var parameters = "token=" + token;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = client.UploadString(url, parameters);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
}
```

In project 2 where I consume the api, client.UploadString throws a System.Net.WebException - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

When I test the api with the chrome rest client it works with `http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken?token=myToken`

Why can WebClient not find it?

**Solved**

I got this to work thanks to @BrentMannering with a small change to add content length:

```
var url = "http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken?token=" + token;
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = 0; //got an error without this line
var response = request.GetResponse();
var data = response.GetResponseStream();            
string result;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
return Json(result);
```

Comment: are you sure you are doing a POST?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Yes. Using the chrome rest client a POST works. Trying with GET does not. Also client.UploadString(url, parameters) uses POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `UploadString` is sending the data as params, so the routing engine on the API side cannot map to an action, hence the 404. According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the method is encoding to a `Byte[]` prior to uploading, this could be part of the problem.

Try using the `UploadValues` method

```
var url = "http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken";
var nv = new NameValueCollection { { "token", token } };
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var result = client.UploadValues(url, nv);
    return Json(result);
}
```

Otherwise to mimic the test you are doing with the chrome client use `WebRequest`

```
var url = "http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken?token=" + token;
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
var data = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
string result = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
return Json(result);
```

Comment: The first method doesnt work but the second did. I just had to add request.ContentLength = 0;

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient.UploadString` method sends an Http **POST** method.  Did you try to access your APIController with a POST method from the test client ? I am assuming your test client sent a GET request and it worked.

There is a different [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where you can mention the Action method type.

```
var url = "http://localhost:1234/myapi/validatetoken";
var parameters = "token=" + token;
string method = "GET"; //or POST as needed
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   var result = client.UploadString(url,method , parameters);
   return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Using the test client, only a POST works. I tried using your overload but it did not work either. Same exception.

Comment: Is the port number correct ? put visual studio breakpoints and copy the url from the code and try that in your rest client

Comment: Still fails. I also tried adding the same headers from the rest client but that didnt work either